# rewrite get variables in url

Tags: .htaccess, web

I'm working on a website and now i want to edit the htaccess file to change a url with get variable. But i look on the internet for information without any success.

http://xxxxx.domain/massage.php?massage={massageName}

this is the link and i want it to look like this

http://xxxxx.domain/massage/{massageName}

Can someone help me with that??

Martijn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+massage\.php\?massage=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /massage/%1? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^massage/(.+)$ /massage.php?massage=$1 [L,QSA]
```

1. Make sure to turn **off** Multiviews, which is a mod_negotiation feature that will pre-emptively affect the request before mod_rewrite can run.
2. You need a rule to redirect the browser from the query string URL to the nicer looking URL, then the browser will send a second request for the nicer looking URL
3. You then need a rule to internally rewrite the nicer looking URL to the one with the query string. This happens entirely on the server's end.

Comment: @mbakker1996 this is probably because your content uses relative links instead of absolute links. Relative links requires the browser to choose a relative URI base, and it does so based on what it shows in the location bar. The location bar now contains an extra `/` path so instead of going to `/main.css` it goes to `/massage/main.css`. The browser doesn't know anything about rewrites internal to the server. So either change your links to absolute URLs (they start with a `/`) or add a URL base to your page headers: `<base href="/" />`